# Question using induction to prove an inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

Could someone help me to prove this inequality using the induction method?

$n \in\mathbb{N}$ (Naturals)

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\ ...\ +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq\sqrt{n}$$

I did the basis step ($n=1$), but I got stuck at the second step (induction step).

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to use Latex and MathJax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the induction step is as follows for $n\geq1$:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{\sqrt n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}} 
\geq \sqrt n + \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}}$$
by the induction hypothesis.

Now you have to prove that for the right-hand side,

$$ \sqrt n + \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}}\geq \sqrt{n+1}.$$

Consider the difference of these expressions. Then
$$ \sqrt n + \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}} - \sqrt{n+1} =
\frac{\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1} + 1 - \sqrt {n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}} = 
\frac{\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}-n}{\sqrt{n+1}}.$$
The numerator is $\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1} - n=\sqrt{n(n+1)}-n = \sqrt{n^2+n} - n\geq 0$ and so the above expression is $\geq 0$ as required.

Comment: Hi, how did you get to the second line proof?

Comment: @Colao: please see comment.

Comment: yeah i've just understood now, thanks!

Comment: If the second line is true, then "sqrt(n+1)" will be also smaller than the LHS of first line, right? (correct me If I'm wrong, please)

Comment: @DanielSehnColao: right!